# Deploying python + mongoDB + node.js

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb

I'm looking for a hosting service that allows deploying a **plain** python program (that will run business logics, manipulating the DB). I also want to be able to use it with MongoDB and to deploy a node.js server with it.
I tried using [Modulus](https://modulus.io) but found out they only support web based python projects. The problem is that I need to run a plain python project. Searching the web only brings up Django hosting services. Can you recommend a suitable alternative? Thank you

Comment: Try mongolab for separating your database from the project .  As far as running python script is consered . check out http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud/ . and for node.js web hosting anything will do - heroku, openshift ,etc .

Comment: Thank you, Heroku works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deploy your solution manually on a VPS with a static IP adress (virtual private server. Providers: OVH (tried it, awesome), win-vps, Ghandi...).

For 5$/month you have a full acces to a Linux server in which you can run whatever you want.
In a VPS you can also run/host a cluster of Docker containers and then separate the data container from the applicative ones.

With a VPS and Docker, you can scale a MongoDB DB server for example.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a service that has mongoDB built in. Any other alternative?